# ADFS Claims Rule Issue

Tags: ldap, adfs3.0

I am attempting to create a custom claim rule in ADFS but I am at a loss as to how to do it.  I have the following for users in my AD:

```
ObjectClass = PrivatePerson
Attribute = PrivatePersonAttribute1
```

I need to be able to return the value for the attribute in the claim as NameID.  Anyone have any suggestions, I am at a complete loss here?

Answer (score 0):

The claims rule wizard in ADFS is editable i.e. you can enter data in the "dropdown".

So create an LDAP rule that maps PrivatePersonAttribute1 to something like http://company.com/PrivatePersonAttribute1

These values won't be in the dropdown so you have to enter them.

Then create a Transform rule that maps http://company.com/PrivatePersonAttribute1 to NameID, You should probably choose a format as well e.g. email or UPN.